# Как сделать, чтобы код продолжал выполняться?

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы, списки

Привет всем! Есть такое задание:

> Вам дается последовательность целых чисел и вам нужно ее обработать и
>   вывести на экран сумму первой пятерки чисел из этой
>   последовательности, затем сумму второй пятерки, и т. д.
>
> Но последовательность не дается вам сразу целиком. С течением времени
>   к вам поступают её последовательные части. Например, сначала первые
>   три элемента, потом следующие шесть, потом следующие два и т. д.
>
> Реализуйте класс Buffer, который будет накапливать в себе элементы
>   последовательности и выводить сумму пятерок последовательных элементов
>   по мере их накопления.
>
> Одним из требований к классу является то, что он не должен хранить в
>   себе больше элементов, чем ему действительно необходимо, т. е. он не
>   должен хранить элементы, которые уже вошли в пятерку, для которой была
>   выведена сумма.

Пример работы с классом

```
buf = Buffer()
buf.add(1, 2, 3)
buf.get_current_part() # вернуть [1, 2, 3]
buf.add(4, 5, 6) # print(15) – вывод суммы первой пятерки элементов
buf.get_current_part() # вернуть [6]
buf.add(7, 8, 9, 10) # print(40) – вывод суммы второй пятерки элементов
buf.get_current_part() # вернуть []
buf.add(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1) # print(5), print(5) – вывод сумм третьей и четвертой пятерки
buf.get_current_part() # вернуть [1]
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно поправить, чтобы продолжил выполняться код после того, как список arr опустеет? На последней проверке, как в примере, arr очищается, в списке buff остаются пять единиц, но добавляться в arr не хотят. Если кто-то откликнется, заранее большое спасибо!

```
class Buffer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.arr = []
    buff = []
    def add(self, *a):
        self.a = a
        self.buff.extend(a)
        for i in self.buff:
            if len(self.arr) < 5:
                self.arr.append(i)
                continue            
        if len(self.arr) >= 5:
            print(sum(self.arr))
            del self.buff[0:5]
        self.arr.clear()
    def get_current_part(self):
        return self.buff
```

Comment: Не используйте текст задания в качестве вопроса. Выделите текущую вашу проблему, явно укажите её в заголовке (представьте что вы в поисковом запросе в гугл написали бы, чтобы найти решение). Опишите своими словами, что фрагмент кода должен делать и что вместо этого происходит. В самом *конце* вопроса, а не в начале, можно для *контекста* привести задание, но вопрос должен быть ясен и без него¶ Не ясно пример кода у вас это неудачное решение или часть задания? Входную коллекцию в виде генератора лучше задать.

Comment: В сторону: чтобы входную коллекцию по 5 чисел за раз обходить и вывести сумму для каждой пятёрки: [`for quintuple in zip(*[iter(input_numbers())]*5): print(sum(quintuple)`](https://goo.gl/ri0i5B)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам не нужна дополнительная переменная buff для реализации задачи. Я упростил ваш код, исключив использование лишней переменной и использовав while вместо for, а также добавил вывод остатка вместе с возвратом для наглядности.

```
class Buffer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.arr = []


    def add(self, *a):
        self.arr.extend(a)
        while len(self.arr) >= 5:
            print(sum(self.arr[:5]))
            del self.arr[0:5]

    def get_current_part(self):
        print(self.arr)
        return self.arr
```

Результат на ваших данных:

```
[1, 2, 3]
15
[6]
40
[]
5
5
[1]
```

Этот код может быть неэффективен на больших входных данных.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Действительно, куда как проще! =)